# Control YouTube player from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, javascript-injection, jquery-events

I am developing a Google Chrome extension that needs to take over **all** the controls of a YouTube video (play, pause, next, previous, change the volume, start video at X seconds, etc). I tried the following approaches:

### First approach: with content_scripts

My `manifest.json` contains the following:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["scripts/jquery.js", "scripts/in_page.js"]
    }
],
```

I'm loading the scripts for every YouTube link, and not only `/watch*` because now YouTube navigation is fully using AJAX, therefore the page is not entirely refreshed, and if I was on a search page and then clicked on a video, the extension wouldn't have loaded my `content_scripts`.

#### How I took over the controls

I successfully managed to trigger simple click events on the YouTube player, such as Play, Pause, Previous video, Next video.

For instance, this works to pause the video:

```
$("#player-api .html5-video-controls .ytp-button-pause").trigger("click");
```

But it seems that I can't trigger events such as clicking on the progress bar to play from a specific moment of the video or restart the video.

I tried this piece of code without success (using jQuery's `$.Event`):

```
var click = $.Event("click");
click.clientX = 0; // Beginning of the video
click.clientY = 0; // I also tried several other coordinates
$("#player-api .html5-video-controls .html5-progress-bar").trigger(click);
```

(And I also tried clicking on every child of the `.html5-progress-bar`, but nothing worked.)

### Second approach: with an injected script

As I seemed to have encountered a dead-end with my first approach, I then tried something else: injecting a script directly inside the page.

My `manifest.json` contains the following:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["scripts/jquery.js", "scripts/isolated.js"]
    }
],

"web_accessible_resources": [
    "scripts/injected.js"
],
```

#### Contents of `isolated.js`

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("scripts/injected.js");
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

#### Contents of `injected.js`

Well, this is where I encountered my second dead-end. I may have overlooked some things, but I searched in every object inside the page, I found `yt`, `ytplayer`, `player`, and others. But none of them seem to have proper functions to trigger changes on the player such as play/pause/next, etc.

I then downloaded the `html5player.js` from YouTube ([available here](https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/html5player-fr_FR-vflu_6hLH/html5player.js)) and beautified it to take a peek at what was under the hood. I found some interesting function names such as `playVideoAt`, `playVideo`, `pauseVideo` around the lines 20235-20315 (once beautified).

That would be exactly the functions I would want to call/invoke, but I don't know where they are, and how to call them.

***I also know that YouTube has a JavaScript API to control the player, but it's only for embedded players (iframes), so it's not useful in my case.***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you're using YouTube's HTML5 video player. In that case you can just interface with the `<video>` DOM element. It happens to be the only `<video>` element on the page, so just do:

```
$('video').play()
$('video').pause()
$('video').currentTime = 100
```

The interface is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods).

As for previous and next videos, you're almost certainly right that the easiest thing to do is:

```
$('.ytp-button-next').click()
$('.ytp-button-prev').click()
```

Since that obviously isn't a published API you have no guarantee those class names will stay the same in future.

Comment: Well, needless to say, it clearly was quite simpler than I would have thought. Thanks a lot! Oh and by the way, this only appears to work inside an injected script (not a content script).

Comment: I was mistaken, it works in the content_scripts aswell, but only by using `document.getElementsByName("video")[0]`, as the `$("video").play()` raises that `play` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but you can use the API's Youtube provides. Take a look here: https://github.com/kurtextrem/StopAutoplay/blob/master/src/main.js

However, there is another way: The element '#movie_player' provides all these functions as well. So getting movie_player by its ID and then executing "playVideoAt" works.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but I recently created a chrome extension for same: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-playback-control/okbcoijdeebocmahlanbfemnckjonfnh

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helps. I have one question - How have you handled message passing between tabId and popup.js? To be specific who is listening "toggle_video_state" message and what are you doing when you receive this message?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta You can specify in content_scripts section a js file which gets added to every page that matches provided urls. In that js file you can specify onMesasgeListener which is a chrom api. Also check github repo here: https://github.com/shahankit/youtube-playback-control

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late, but I think it can still help someone. If you wish to control HTML5 video player using jQuery within `content_scripts`, then you can get the video element using `$("video")[0]` and then use that to trigger a valid event, e.g.

```
$("video")[0].pause()
$("video")[0].play()
..
```